# Removing duplicate values over multiple columns sql server

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I created a small app at work for my personal use that displays information based city lookups. I am running into and issue where some data is duplicated because the same values can be in any of 3 columns.

**Example Query**

```
SqlCommand cmd6 = new SqlCommand("SELECT Distinct County1, County2, County3 from table where StateId=" + "'" + State + "'" + " AND City=" + "'" + City + "'", con);
using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd6.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                this.County.Text += rdr["County1"].ToString() + " ";
                this.County.Text += rdr["County2"].ToString()+ " ";
                this.County.Text += rdr["County3"].ToString() + " ";
            }
        }

        con.Close();
```

**Output: for Auburn, Alabama**

```
 CHAMBERS CHAMBERS CHAMBERS LEE CHAMBERS LEE LEE
```

Chambers and Lee can be in either County1, County2 based on how they were entered into the DB. Instead of starting from scratch, I am wondering if it is possible to check for duplicates in the SQL statement prior to putting it into the string. Maybe display the unique values between the 3 columns when the columns are compared? Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would putting the values in one column work?

```
select Distinct v.county
from table t cross apply
     (values (t.county1), (t.county2), (t.county3)) v(county)
where v.county is not null and
      StateId=" + "'" + State + "'" + " AND City=" + "'" + City + "'",
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon-Lindoff this was what I needed.